# c# generic method for mathematical operations

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to create a generic method which performs basic mathematical operations. For eg. If a **double** is passed to the function, it will return **double**.

```
public static T Multiply<T> (T A, int B)
{
   //some calculation here
   return (T) A * B; 
}
```

This doesn't work for me.

**EDIT**: I get an error Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'int'

However I am wondering if there are other ways to achieve what I am trying to?

Thanks

Comment: And what does not work exactly?

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html

Comment: You can't do that, and there's no constraint you can apply such that `*` is defined for all `T`. However, some smart people have put some work into producing a [Generic Operators](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html) implementation.

Comment: As a hold-over, especially if you aren't _too_ concerned with super fast performance and like to _live dangerously_ with possible runtime exceptions, you can cast `A` to `dynamic` before multiplying and let the DRL do the heavy work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by constructing and compiling a LINQ expression for the specific type, like this:

```
private static IDictionary<Type,object> MultByType = new Dictionary<Type,object>();
public static T Multiply<T>(T a, int b) {
    Func<T,int,T> mult;
    object tmp;
    if (!MultByType.TryGetValue(typeof (T), out tmp)) {
        var lhs = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var rhs = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
        mult = (Func<T,int,T>) Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Multiply(lhs, Expression.Convert(rhs, typeof(T)))
        ,   lhs
        ,   rhs
        ).Compile();
        MultByType.Add(typeof(T), mult);
    } else {
        mult = (Func<T,int,T>)tmp;
    }
    return mult(a, b);
}
```

To avoid recompiling the expression each time it is used, one could cache it in a dictionary.

Note that this approach has certain limitations:

- Multiplication of `T` by `T` is expected to be defined,
- The output of multiplication is expected to be `T` without conversion. This is not true for types smaller than `int`,
- The type must support conversion from `int`.

None of this is checked at compile time.

Comment: To cache it without the dictionary lookup/casting/threadsafety, couldn't you wrap this in a `static Multiplicator<T>` class where the compilation is performed in its static constructor and the cached delegate stored as a static field?

Comment: It's also worth noting that in this code sample there is no compile time verification that `T` actually has a `*` binary operator defined.

Comment: @Servy "t's also worth noting that in this code sample there is no compile time verification..." That's a fair point, I edited the answer to mention it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks @dasblinkenlight. It does what I need but I was hoping that there might a simple way to achieve this. I'll have to decide if i really want to use this in production.

Comment: @dopplesoldner [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) already has [generic operators](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html), so that you don't have to code it. See [usage example](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest to implement, but is not efficient:

```
  public static T Multiply<T>(T A, int B)
  {
     T val = default(T);
     try
     {
        val = (dynamic)A * B;
     }
     catch
     { }

     return val;
  }
```

Depending on your needs it might be fine for you.  You may consider not handling the exception in the method, or using an `out` value so that you can return both the answer and a success value.

Comment: You may want to consider catching a `RuntimeBinderException` which represents that a matching operator doesn't exist, instead of a general catch-all. I know code _generally shouldn't_ throw when executing operators, but if it does, you probably want that to be thrown rather than swallowed. (I _think_ `RuntimeBinderException` is the only one you need to check for.)

Answer (score 0):

Being stuck on an on older .Net version, without access to dynamic, I have a very simple class that does very much what you're looking for, and allows for use of actual operators: [Numeric](https://github.com/mattbenic/Numeric) It may be worth a look on current .Net as well.

Method declaration:

```
public static T LerpMinMax<T>(Numeric<T> input, Numeric<T> inputMin, Numeric<T> inputMax, Numeric<T> outputMin, Numeric<T> outputMax)
{
     if (input <= inputMin)
     {
        return outputMin;
     }
     else if (input >= inputMax)
     {
        return outputMax;
     }
     return outputMin + ((input - inputMin) / (inputMax - inputMin)) * (outputMax - outputMin);
}
```

And then use:

```
float lerp = LerpMinMax<float>(0.55f, 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 1000.0f);
```

It's definitely not as flexible as MiscUtil's Operator, but was intended to be simple and (relatively) fast. It's still significantly slower than using operations directly (say by using T4 templates that spit out non-generic type-specific implementations) but used in the above way it's equivalent to MiscUtil's Operator class. It also obviously has the benefit of generally more readable algorithm implementations, and can support custom classes that implement operators.

Answer (score 0):

You should add Dynamic in front of the A
and the conversion to T must be done on the full calculation

```
public static T Multiply<T>(T A, int B)
{
   return (T)((dynamic)A * B);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my example for using generics to compare to numbers:

```
    public bool TIsEqual<T>(T f1, T f2, T margin)
    {
        T diff = default(T);
        T error = default(T);
        diff = Math.Abs((dynamic)f1 - f2);
        error = (dynamic)margin * f1;
        return (dynamic) diff < error;
    }
```